# iphone - Draw a line in UITableViewCell when background view is set

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, drawing, drawrect

I have written drawRect as follows.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef cxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cxt, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cxt, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(cxt, 250.0 , 0.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cxt, 250.0, 50.0);
   CGContextStrokePath(cxt);
}
```

It draws red line. But When I set background view to cell line disappears. I have set view as follow.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.backgroundView = view;
```

What is the problem? How backgrond view hides the line?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are in a `UITableViewCell`?

You should not overwrite `drawRect` of the cell itself. Instead put your drawing code in a custom `backgroundView`, or in a custom view within the `contentView` hierarchy. (depends on your planned result, probably backgroundView is correct for you)

The line is gone, because the `backgroundView` is a subview of the TableViewCell, so it is on top of the cell itself. (You can see this, if you use `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]` as backgroundColor of your backgroundView.) There are many views on a UITableViewCell, it looks somewhat like this:

```
UITableViewCell
  > BackgroundView
  > (EditControl) 
  > ContentView
  > (AccessoryView)
```

Comment: K but as name suggest background it should be at bottom. Now I got. Thank you

Comment: it is at the bottom. its the first subview. but a subview cannot be below its own superview - how should this work ,)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with jaydee3 that you should not override UITableViewCell's drawRect, instead make your custom view class extending from UIView, extend drawRect there and do all the framing and coloring thing there, then set an instance of that view as your cell background view, its much better approach

Answer (score 0):

When u already drawn background of that,u can't set background Color or image again for that cell.It overlays on what u drawn.